# Help translating inscription and seal

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal, calligraphy, transcription

I was recently gifted this painting and I’m curious about the painter. A friend said the painting indicates it was done in Autumn 1980, but she couldn’t read the painter or buyers name. I would appreciate help with the translation. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The artist's name is 「葉潛德」 (Mandarin Pinyin: **Yè Qiándé**).

---

Calligraphy:

> 庚申深秋 // 潛德寫
> Written on the end of autumn in the [year of *gēngshēn*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%BA%9A%E7%94%B3#Chinese) by 潛德 (**Qiándé**)

Seal 1:

> 潛德書画
> Drawn and written by 潛德

Seal 2:

> 葉氏
> Clan 葉 (**Yè**)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Amanda If you satisfy with the answer, an "up-tick" is better than thousand words.

Comment: Thanks for telling me. I clicked the uptick button and it said it was recorded but that I needed fifteen reputation points for it to display and I don’t have that. I’m sorry if I can’t be more helpful.

Comment: @Amanda I got it. I am up-voting your post :)

Comment: Great. Thank you so much!

Comment: @r13  "英雄救美"  : )

Comment: @WayneCheah 一日一善 :)